# Why SecurityFactoryInterface#getKey returns string in hypen-separated case?

Tags: php, symfony, bundle

I failed to find out, where 'simple_preauth' security config parameter comes from, by searching for that string through the project. Later i figured out that actual value is 'simple-preauth'.

```
 public function getKey()
 {
     return 'simple-preauth';
 }
```

In [authentication factories](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/SecurityBundle/DependencyInjection/Security/Factory/SimplePreAuthenticationFactory.php#L31) it returns values like that, but in security config it's

```
firewalls:
    main:
       simple_preauth:
```

The case is changed to snake-case in [MainConfiguration#addFirewallsSection](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/SecurityBundle/DependencyInjection/MainConfiguration.php#L285).

```
str_replace('-', '_', $factory->getKey())
```

Why it's made that way?